# Looping en diccionarios

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un problema con diccionarios en python.

¿Cómo hago para obtener la clave de un diccionario a partir del valor?.

Es decir, si tuviera un diccionario de la forma;

```
d={"key1":
  {"key2":
  {"e":5,"f":8,....,"z":10}}}
```

y quiero saber que clave contiene el valor 50.

Comment: No veo ningún 50 en el diccionario de muestra :O A todo esto, ¿qué intentaste?

Answer (score 0):

```
d={"key1":{"key2":{"e":5,"f":8,"z":10}}}

def buscar(d, criterio, p = ""):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            buscar(v, criterio, "{} > {}".format(p, k))
        elif v == criterio:
            print("{} > {} : {}".format(p, k, v))

buscar(d, 10)
```

El resultado sería: > key1 > key2 > z : 10

Saludos

Comment: No esta de más recordar que cualquier solución recursiva de Python tiene un límite en la profundidad de la recursión, por defecto este número es 1000. Saludos.